# XSLT choose first match

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have a xml with the strucure:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>abc</c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>efg</c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>efg</c>
    <d>1-123456789</d>
    <d>2-123456789</d>
  </b>
  <b>
    <d>1-123400000</d>
    <d>2-123400000</d>
    <d>3-123400000</d>
  </b>
</a>
```

How do I select the first occurance of d? `a/b/d[1]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. In the following example:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>c1</c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>c2</c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>c3</c>
    <d>d1</d>
    <d>d2</d>
  </b>
  <b>
    <d>d3</d>
    <d>d4</d>
    <d>d5</d>
  </b>
</a>
```

the instruction (given from the context of the root node `/`):

```
<xsl:copy-of select="a/b/d[1]"/>
```

returns:

```
<d>d1</d>
<d>d3</d>
```

while:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="(a/b/d)[1]"/>
```

will return:

```
<d>d1</d>
```

Comment: yes, sorry I had made a mistake, I've updated it. I want to apply xslt template to the first occurance of "d" in the whole document.

Comment: @Rnet then `<xsl:apply-templates select="(//d)[1]"/>` is what you need.

Comment: @IanRoberts unfortunately that does not work, "Parentheses are not allowed in an XSLT 2.0 pattern". I'm using saxon parser

Comment: @IanRoberts Sorry, my mistake, I used the parantheses in the template match too. It works now, thank you!

Comment: @Rnet you can't use parentheses in a `match` pattern (apart from in a predicate) but you can use them when you `select` which nodes to apply templates _to_.

Comment: @Rnet `"(a/b/d)[1]"` selects the fist occurrence of `a/b/d` (the first `d` that is a child of `b` that is a child of `a`) in the entire document. `"(//d)[1]"` selects the first occurrence of `d` **anywhere** in the document tree.

Answer (score 2):

### You can select the first occurrence of `d` as follows:

**If you want to cover different ancestral structure above `d`:**

```
(//d)[1]
```

**If you know the ancestral structure above `d` is fixed:**

```
/a/b[3]/d[1]
```

Comment: `//d[1]` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::d[1]`, i.e. _all_ `d` elements that are the first `d` under their respective parents.  It would return two nodes (the first `d` under each of the 3rd and fourth `b` elements), if you want just the first one in the whole document you need `(//d)[1]` or `/descendant::d[1]`